# Laravel - Update dynamic fields in relationship table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables **Cars** and **Features**, where Cars and Features have one to many relations.

Cars table has `ID`, `Name` columns. Features tables has `ID`, `CarID`, `Name`, `Feat Image`.

When I update the details, Cars table updated Features table is not updated.

**Cars.php**

```
public function features() {
    return $this->hasMany(Features::class, 'cars_id');
}
```

**Features.php**

```
public function feat()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Cars::class, 'cars_id');
}
```

**Controller.php**

Update Method

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{        
    $requestData = $request->all();
    $cars = Cars::findOrFail($id);
    $features = Features::with(['feat'])->where('cars_id', $cars->id)->get();

    if($cars->update($requestData))
        {
            if ($request->hasFile('feat_img')) 
            {
                $file = $request->file('feat_img');
                $rules = array('file' => 'required|mimes:png,gif,jpeg'); 
                $validator = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make(array('file'=> $file), $rules);
                if($validator->passes()) 
                {
                    $name = $request->name;
                    for ($i=0; $i < count(request('name')); ++$i) 
                    {
                    $features->name = request('name')[$i];
                    $feat_img_name = uniqid() . '.' . $images[$i]->getClientOriginalExtension();
                    $images[$i]->move(public_path('/images/'), $feat_img_name);            
                    $features->feat_img = '/images/'.$feat_img_name;   
                }
             }
         }
    $cars->features()->update($features);
    session()->flash('message', 'Product updated successfully.');
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Store Method

```
public function store(Request $request, Cars $cars)
{
  $cars= new Cars;
  $cars->name= request('name');
  $cars->image= $image;

   if($cars->save())
    {
     $features= [];
       $images = $request->file('feat_img');
       $name = $request->name;

        for ($i=0; $i < count(request('name')); ++$i) 
        {
        $features= new Features;
        $features->name = request('name')[$i];
        $feat_img_name = uniqid() . '.' . $images[$i]->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $images[$i]->move(public_path('/images/'), $feat_img_name);            
        $features->feat_img = '/images/'.$feat_img_name;
        $cars->features()->save($features);
        }
session()->flash('message','Product successfully added.'); 
        return redirect ('/');
    }
}
```

[image: Features Form]

Comment: `$features` is collections of object, you are assigning values to collections

Comment: But I can I save the details from ``Store`` method.

Comment: then add that too, it will explain us better

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Change this line to `$features = Features::with(['feat'])->where('cars_id', $cars->id)->first();`, your store method creating single instance but when you are using `->get()`, its making collections of object, you need to have single instance

Comment: It gave error ``Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::update() must be of the type array, object given, called in...``

Comment: use this line `$features->save();` instead of `$cars->features()->update($features);`

Comment: It returned no errors! but did not update the table too.

Comment: I updated question with form screenshot. Method executed successfully but table not updated.

Comment: i would suggest you, in your update, delete existing related models `$car->features()->delete()`, then insert those new features

Answer (score 1):

Use update like this :

```
$features=Features::findOrFail(id);
$features->field=$value;
$features->save();
```

Hope this works.

Comment: If I use ``$features=Features::findOrFail(id);``, it failes and throws Page Not Found error.